# Rails 4 - heroku production version not incorporating js or images

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to figure out what's going wrong with my deployment in production to Heroku.

My local host files all work.

I have app/assets/js folder with a file called application.js, which has:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require html.sortable
//= require bootstrap-slider
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require pickers
//= require main
//= require npm
//= require hammer.min
//= require jquery.animate-enhanced.min
//= require jquery.countTo
//= require jquery.easing.1.3
//= require jquery.fitvids
//= require jquery.magnific-popup.min
//= require jquery.parallax-1.1.3
//= require jquery.properload
//= require jquery.shuffle.modernizr.min
//= require jquery.sudoSlider.min
//= require jquery.superslides.min
//= require masonry.pkgd.min
//= require rotaterator
//= require smoothscrolljs
//= require waypoints.min
//= require wow.min
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require dependent-fields
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require cocoon
//= require imagesloaded.pkgd.min
//= require isotope.pkgd.min
//= require circle-progress
//= require jquery.counterup.min
//= require jquery.pjax
//= require custom.js
//= require_tree .
```

In my app/assets/stylesheets folder. I have a file called application.css.scss, which has:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'bootstrap-datetimepicker';
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "bootstrap-slider";
@import "chosen";
@import "animate";
@import "magnific-popup";
@import "simple-line-icons";
@import "shortcodes";
@import "style";
@import "text";
@import "variable";


@import "addresses.scss";
@import "articles.scss";
@import "common.scss";
@import "footer.scss";
@import "forms.scss";
@import "glyphs.scss";
@import "index.scss";
@import "legal.scss";
@import "navigation.scss";
@import "pages.scss";
@import "profiles.scss";
@import "profile2.scss";
@import "video.scss";
```

I also have app/assets/images folder. It has several .jpg and .png files as well as favicon.ico

In my application.rb, I have

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'


# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    config.time_zone = 'London'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails}/vendor/assets/fonts"

    config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)

    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

    config.secret_key_base = Figaro.env.secret_key_base

    # I18n.available_locales = [:en, :ru]

    # config.active_record.observers = :video_observer

    # config.active_record.observers = :user_observer

    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/services)
  end
end
```

In my production.rb, I have

```
# Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  # config.serve_static_assets = true
  # config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js'] 
  # config.assets.precompile += %w(*.js *.css *.svg *.eot *.woff *.ttf *.gif *.png *.ico)


  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
```

In my config initialiser/assets.rb file I have:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Add additional assets to the asset load path
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( surveyor_all.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( surveyor_all.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( index.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.jpg *.gif *.png *.ico )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( favicon.ico )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( application.css )
```

I have tried several times over running rake precompile assets and to run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`. I can't get anything to work.

The javascript that works fine in the development version doesn't work in production. Images are not rendering. I cannot figure out why. All js files used in the application are listed in `application.js`. Some of the required files are stored in the vendor folder. Similarly, all css files are listed in the `application.css.scss` file and all images are in app assets images folder.

Does anyone know how to deploy to Heroku with all files included?

Examples (there are many, of things that don't work:

1. Image

   ```
    <div class="hero-section parallax-bg dark-layer"
   ```

   data-background= "<%= image_path "cropdust.jpg" %>" >

The above image is stored in my app assets images folder. It just renders a blank panel (in production).

2. CSS

I have a panel of content with div tabs and ids. The tabs are supposed to move when an id is clicked. They don't, the panel is stuck on the first tab:

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="dp-tab-1">
                                <ul class="dp-tab-list row" id="myTab">
                                    <li class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 active" >
                                        <a href="#tab-content-first">

                                            <span>THE OLD WAY</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                                        <a href="#tab-content-second">

                                            <span>direct</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                                        <a href="#tab-content-third">



                                            <span>MYTHs</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                                        <a href="#tab-content-fourth">

                                            <span>OUR APPROACH</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="dp-tab-content tab-content">
                                    <div class="tab-pane row fade in active" id="tab-content-first">
                                        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">

                                            <%= image_tag "oldway.jpg", :class=>"wow fadeInLeft img-responsive", :alt=>"The old fashioned way" %>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="tab-inner">
                                                <h4> INEFFICIENT</h4>
                                                <p class='medium-text'>
                                                    With:
                                                    <ul class='medium-text'>
                                                        <li class='medium-text'>- grant  routinely dwarfed 
                                                    </ul>     
                                                </p>

                                                <p class='medium-text'>
                                                    It's beyond clear, that 
                                                </p>


                                                <br/>
                                                <a class='btn btn-info btn-line'>READ MORE</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane row fade" id="tab-content-second">
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <div class="tab-inner">
```

3. JS

   ```
       <span class="countTo" data-from="356" data-to="0" data-speed="3000">0</span>

     </div>
   ```

Comment: Do you have the code where you are calling the images / javascript (your javascript include tags)? Because an individual file will have a different name post-compiled vs pre-confiled (even an image file will change names).

Comment: Try looking at the logs.. What errors are you getting? Also, are you getting any error code with the rake assets:precompile?

Comment: Chris - I don't get any errors after precompiling - it just doesnt work to render the page as it should (and does in development)

Comment: Ryan - I added some examples - there are at least 20 on the single home page.

Answer (score 1):

make sure the following are true in your production.rb file

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

I had similar issues on heroku where the stars for jquery raty plugin were broken eventhough in development everything worked just fine.

Adding the above settings did the job for me. I see that they are false in the config/production.rb file you have posted